# How to depress the onLongClick() when drag a view?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a Activity and I can drag finger on it with `onFling()` method (I'm implementing from `OnGestureListener`). It also has a `onLongClick()` method so it can respond to the long press on the screen. Now, i wanna disable `onLongClick()` method, when long press on the screen and move finger the `onFling()` will be triggered instead of `onLongClick()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer isn't working, then please post your code so we can determine what's not working and why.

Answer (score 0):

XML:

`android:longClickable="false"`

Code:

`view.setLongClickable(false)`